# Mysql sum previous record value with condition

Tags: mysql

i have a table called 'po_table' where i wanted to sum the previous record qty value but sum of should be cleared when its go to next set (here id)
po_table is below

```
id     qty
 1     10
 1      3
 1      1
 2     34
 2      4
 3      2
```

The result i want is,

```
id     qty
 1     10
 1     13
 1     14
 2     34
 2     38 
 3      2
```

my code was ,

```
select id, (@sum := @sum + qty) as qty
from po_table
 cross join
     (select @sum := 0) params
```

Here it continuously sum the previous value for the entire table rows which is i dont want only sum the values until the id field value changes.
pls help me on this

thanks and regards

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also what did you tried so far to solve your problem and what went wrong?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
select id, 
       @sum := case when @prev = id 
                    then @sum + qty 
                    else qty 
               end as qty,       
       @prev := id
from po_table
 cross join
     (select @sum := 0, @prev := 0) params
order by id
```

Comment: This kind of thing always requires an ORDER BY clause